# method give null array instead of full data while using forEach loop in node js for cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want a Fully response in JSON like,

```
[
   {
      "email":"a",
      "product":[
         {
            "price":100,
            "veg_name":"Potato",
            "stock":"10"
         },
         {
            "stock":"10",
            "price":"100",
            "veg_name":"Tomato"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "email":"amp",
      "product":[
         {
            "price":"1000",
            "veg_name":"ffdf"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

This type of JSON data will store in fullDatas object in below code. on the fully completion of forEach loop. we can see this via console. But, Response in always like, [] means null.

```
let stockRef = firestore.collection('stock');
    const fullDatas = [];
    //stock
    let final = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stockRef.get().then(documents => {
            documents.forEach(doc => {
                let data = {};
                //single select like 'a'
                data['email'] = doc.data()['email'];
                const product = [];

                let colRef = stockRef.doc(doc.id).collection('Product');
                colRef.get().then(vegDocs => {
                    vegDocs.forEach(veg => {
                        product.push(veg.data());
                    });
                    data['product'] = product;
                    fullDatas.push(data);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(fullDatas));
                });
            });
            resolve(fullDatas);
        });
    });

    final.then((result) => {
        res.json(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.send(error);
    });
```

What should I change in the above Code?
I think I have implemented the wrong promise.

Comment: because you never wait for `colRef.get()` promise.

Comment: can you teach me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Reading a document reference. I have replacing forEach to for loop and also placed a proper async/await and proper use of Promise.

```
let stockRef = firestore.collection('stock');
    const fullDatas = [];
    //stock
    let final = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stockRef.get().then(async documents => {
            let docs = documents.docs;
            for (let doc of docs) {
                console.log(doc.data());
                let data = {};
                //single select like 'a'
                data['email'] = doc.data()['email'];
                const product = [];

                let colRef = stockRef.doc(doc.id).collection('Product');
                await colRef.get().then(vegSnapshot => {
                    let vegDocs = vegSnapshot.docs;
                    for (let veg of vegDocs) {
                        product.push(veg.data());
                    }
                    data['product'] = product;
                    fullDatas.push(data);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(fullDatas));
                });
            }
            resolve(fullDatas);
        });
    });

    final.then((result) => {
        res.json(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.send(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't make a comment because of reputation rule. However, 
I think the wrong is in this line

```
data['email'] = doc.data()['email'];
```

regarding your code doc.data() is an array with 2 element
and you bass the key 'email' without determining which element you are want to access, 
so I think you need to make another loop here.

Comment: where do you see `doc.data()` is an array?

Comment: No, doc.data() is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Rather using `forEach` and `global/closure []` you can use `Array.prototype.map`.

You need to wait for each and every promise in the chain with `return promise` or `await`.

when you get an array of promises back from `.map` you can use `Promise.all` to wait for each and every promise to be resolved.

```
import { promises } from "fs";

let stockRef = firestore.collection('stock');
//stock
let final = stockRef.get().then(documents => {
    return documents.map(doc => {
        let data = {};
        //single select like 'a'
        data['email'] = doc.data()['email'];
        let colRef = stockRef.doc(doc.id).collection('Product');
        return colRef.get().then(vegDocs => {
            const productPromises = vegDocs.map(veg => veg.data());
            return Promise.all(productPromises).then(product => data['product'] = product);
        }).then(() => data);
    });
}).then(Promise.all);

final.then((result) => {
    res.json(result);
}).catch((error) => {
    res.send(error);
});
```

Comment: It gives an error like, `TypeError: documents.map is not a function at stockRef.get.then.documents`

Comment: console log documents before `return documents.map`

Comment: It's an object of `QuerySnapshot { ... }`

Comment: so how you were using forEach on it?

Comment: Read this. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

Comment: That's another issue I cant relate your snippet with linked snippets.